# How do I install lubicu66 on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: apt, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to install Ezra-project on Ubuntu 20.04. When I run the install it fails and says:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ezra-project:
 ezra-project depends on libicu66; however:
  Package libicu66 is not installed.
```

I tried installing libicu66 with

```
    sudo apt install libicu66
```

But it says

```
Package libicu66 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libicu66' has no installation candidate
```

Is libicu66 available for Ubuntu 20.04? If so, please could someone direct me to where to download it from?

Answer (score 14):

I faced same problem when i tried to install couchdb.
The solution i found was installing it manually.
Go to https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/focal/main/base/libicu66 and download the proper version for your CPU architecture.
It could be done with `wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu66_66.1-2ubuntu2_[YOUR_CPU_ARCHITECTURE].deb`

Then in the same folder use `sudo apt update && sudo dpkg -i libicu66_66.1-2ubuntu2_[YOUR_CPU_ARCHITECTURE].deb`

Comment: Worth noting that this also allows the installation of libicu66 with later versions of Ubuntu (e.g. Ubuntu 21)