# R-installation with Linux Mint 21

Tags: r, linux-mint

Can I please get some help with installing R in a Linux-Mint 21 System, which I installed just recently. (So I am an absolute beginner...) I tried, however failed again and again. I added a picture of the response.

[image: Picture of Response]

Main part says that r-base-core is dependend on libicu66, which is not installable. Than it says that a lot of packages are multiple configured (??) and in the and that the problems are not possible to correct and that I have withhold and defective packages...

Thanks in advance for advice, what to do...

Comment: You apparently attempted to install a ubuntu version. To solve your second issue, do `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` and try to remove duplicated repos.

Comment: This might be a question for https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Thanks jay.sf. That was helpful with the second issue. At the moment I left only the vanessa repo. 
Concerning Ubuntu: R is compatible to Ubuntu oder debian. However, Mint, I learned depends on Ubuntu... Thus in earlier versions installation of ubuntu - R on Mint was done. 
Or am I totally wrong?

Comment: @drjokl Apparently it doesn't work. Try install libicu66, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65647087/6574038 (Note: Please use @ when notifying users in comments)

Comment: @jay.sf Thank you. It seemed to have worked. R was installed, Rstudio as well.

Comment: @drjokl Nice, did you manage to install libicu66?

Comment: @jay.sf Yes. That seemed to have been key.  Thanks for helping!